# Converting the Date from Numeric format to ddmmyy format in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, date

I am getting a Json response from the WebService where I get the date in "performance_start":1328118600 and I want it to convert it like " 05 April 2011 " in my android application.

I have searched various sites but couldn't found anything worthy, Can any one tell me how exactly I can do this.

Thanks,
david brown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (1328118600*1000));
        System.out.println("Date "+ date);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

first convert performance_start into Long.

```
long createdDateTime = performance_start

Date date = new Date(createdDateTime);
```

then

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,DateFormat.SHORT).format(date);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Sorry, but I am not getting the method "getDateTimeInstance" on pressing the " . (DOT) " with the DateFormat.

Comment: did you imported the java.text.DateFormat